# propositional calculus?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm very stuck on this question in my High School class.

**Atomic Sentances:**

I – I am hungry

M – I will eat pie

V - I will become lazy.

B - I will be happy.

**Hypothesis:**

H1 – $I \implies M \land V$

H2 – $M \implies B$

H3 – $V \implies \neg B$

$I \implies M \land V, M \implies B , V ⇒ \neg B$

Show that 'I am not hungry' follows from the Hypothesis

I think I have to use Proof by contradiction for this but it is really confusing me? can anyone help please?

Comment: Are the hypotheses in bold? I don't understand what T, H, E, O denote.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry about that I have changed that now!

Answer (score 4):

We certainly do obtain a contradiction *if* we also know that $I$ holds. But if "I am not hungry", then "I do not eat pie" does not necessarily follow. So the conclusion necessarily follows if and only if $I$ holds.

If "I" is false, "V" is false, "B" is true, and M is true, all the premises still are true, and since "M" is true under this assignment, we have a consistent conclusion: "I eat the pie."

So the desired conclusion holds provided "I" is true.

**UPDATE, given edit:**

Okay, we can assume that $M \land V$. Then use your hypotheses to derive $B$ and $\lnot B$. Contradiction. Therefore, $\lnot (M \land V)$. Therefore, by modus tollens, $\lnot I$.

$(1) \quad I \implies M \land V\quad \text{hypothesis}$

$(2)\quad M \implies B\quad\quad\text{hypothesis}$

$(3)\quad V \implies \neg B\quad \text{hypothesis}$

$(4)\quad \quad\quad  \underline{M\land V\quad \quad\text{Assumption}}$

$(5)\quad\quad\quad \mid M\quad\quad\quad\text{$(4)\;\land$-elimination}$

$(6)\quad\quad\quad \mid V\quad\quad\quad\text{$(4)\;\land$-elimination}$

$(7)\quad\quad\quad \mid B\quad\quad\text{$(2, 5)\;$modus ponens}$

$(8)\quad\quad\quad \mid \lnot B\quad\quad\text{$(3, 6)\;$modus ponens}$

$(9) \quad\quad\quad\mid \text B \land \lnot B \quad\text{$(7, 8)\;\land$-introduction}$

$(10)\quad\quad\;\; \mid\;\;\perp\quad \quad \text{$(9)$ Contradiction}$

$(11)\quad \lnot(M \land V) \quad\text{$4 - 10\;\;\lnot$-Introduction}$

$(12)\quad \lnot I \quad\text{$(1)\;$ modus tollens}$

Comment: I'm sorry about this.. It wasn't supposed to be 'I do not eat pie'. It was meant to be 'I am not hungry' I copied it out wrong

Comment: So putting this into a Assertions/Justifications tableau how would this look?

Comment: I've Note that there is a subproof beginning with the assumption (step 4) and lasting through step $(10)$, showing that the assumption $M\land V$ yields a contradiction. Then we discharge the assumption concluding that $\lnot (M\land V)$.

Comment: Better put a line character just before first step. I've looked for the first step for a while =)

Comment: @user103186 If the answer has been helpful, please consider accepting it. Just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. (You can only accept one answer per question asked.)

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my dear friend. I hope you have a great hours ahead. Good morning Amy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1._$I$. (assumption)

2.|$M\land V$ (by the first hypothesis and 1)

3.|$M$ (deduce from 2)

4.|$V$ (deduce from 2)

5.|$B$ (by the second hypothesis and 3)

6.|$\neg B$ (by the third hypothesis and 4)

7.|$B\land \neg B$ (from 5 and 6)

8.|contradiction

9.$I$

Comment: You've been very helpful! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

'I am not hungry' shows that we want to get $\neg I$. We recall that the converse negative proposition equals the original proposition. So:

from H1: we have $\neg I\Leftarrow\neg M\vee\neg V\quad (1)$;

from H2: we have $\neg M\Leftarrow\neg B\quad (2)$;

from H3: we have $V\Rightarrow\neg B\quad (3)$ and $B\Rightarrow\neg V \quad (4)$.

With (2) and (3), we have $V\Rightarrow\neg M\quad(5)$, then with (4) and (1) we have:
$$V\vee B\Rightarrow\neg I$$
which means "if 'I become lazy' or 'I am happy', then 'I am not hungry'".

That's all!